# What is the unsung hero badge for?

Tags: discussion, badges, zero-score-badges

I'm extremely confused with the concept of the **Unsung Hero** badge, since it counts the answers that are both accepted and upvoted. It suggests that the questioner will accept an answer but not upvote it. Don't you think it's a bit schizophrenic behaviour? Or the badge is for people who accept their own answert, unable to upvote it?

Comment: It is quite common (at least for me) I have over 20 answers which were accepted but not up-voted.  Still have not gotten this badge -- which is a bummer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [Badges page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges)

> Zero score accepted answers: more than 10 and 25% of total

It's to reward those people who's **answers** are accepted **but not upvoted**. This can be for many reasons - one being that new users can post questions and accept answers, but can't up-vote until they get 15 rep, another being where there are few users who are knowledgeable in a tag.

So it's a way of rewarding those people who help the new users to the site.

I don't think self accepted answers count.

Comment: Another reason: in many more obscure tags (past top 10 especially) such answers are quite usual. So, it seems more like a consolation badge.

Comment: @Nikita - good point.

Comment: Isn't user always able to upvote in his own question? Still, would make sense for me if upvote from acceptant wouldn't count.

Comment: @volkerjaan - no. If the OP could do that then it could lead to the creation of sock-puppet accounts to ask questions which get answered (and at least one up-vote) by the main account. The 15 rep threshold doesn't stop this, but it means a *bit* more work for the cheater.

Comment: Some tags — the security-related ones come to mind — have very little in the way of up-voting. I don't know if that's because very few people know much about security or because those that know something think everyone else in the field is an idiot. I _suspect_ that it's a lot of both, alas.

Comment: Another question: If my answer was accepted **when it has 0 score**, but **later upvoted**, does it still count towards this badge?