# Do votes in the interim before Unsung Hero is awarded affect its criteria?

Tags: discussion, zero-score-badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How long do Tenacious and Unsung Hero badges take to be awarded?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57696/how-long-do-tenacious-and-unsung-hero-badges-take-to-be-awarded)

I have got 10 accepted answers with zero score today and also more than 25% of total.
Therefore I am eligible to get Unsung Hero badges. I heard that it will take a minimum of 10 days to get Unsung Hero badges.

It's fine but in the intervening 10 days, if any one upvotes one of the zero score accepted answers will it still count as a zero accepted answer towards the badge or not? If it does count then it's fine, otherwise someone who wants to get Unsung Hero badges will miss out. Then why should it take more days? Is it necessary?

Another example: if in the ten day window I get more accepted answers with non zero and therefore no longer meet the 'more than 25% of total' requirement, then what will happen?

Comment: Because Unsung Hero badge is given for Being patient. So be patient.:)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've misinterpreted it.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/57834/178438

> - Only accepted answers older than 10 days are considered (otherwise tons of new users would get this)
> - As long as they are not self accept
> - And they are not wiki
> - And they are not deleted

So: For a question to be counted, it must be older than seven days. You have some zero score accepts 1 day ago, 6 days ago, and 9 days ago. These are not counted, yet. This is by design, they should be open for voting for a while at least.

> It's fine but in between 10 days, any one upvote to one of the zero accepted answers. In this case it will count as zero accepted answer or not?

No.

> otherwise some one who want to get Unsung Hero badges that person will be lost. Then why will take more days? Is it necessary?

See my comment above on "by design"

> Another case, in between 10 days, if i will get more accepted answers with non zero i.e i will fail 'more than 25% of total', then what will happen. Please tell me anyone.

You won't get the badge.

There may be a delay in running the badge script as well, after all, it's a big query. Probably run once every few days.

Comment: Seven days or ten?

Answer (score 4):

[`Unsung Hero`](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/226/unsung-hero) badge is to reward those people whose answers are accepted but not upvoted. This can be for many reasons - one being that new users can post questions and accept answers, but can't up-vote until they get 15 rep, another being where there are few users who are knowledgeable in a tag.

So it's a way of rewarding those people who help the new users to the site.

Source : https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/78112/178505

Community assumes your question is active for 10 days. So you can get up-votes until 10 days. And if your question is accepted with zero votes and [criteria for unsung hero](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/57834/178505) is satisfied. You will definitely get the Unsung Hero badge.

**Unsung hero itself means a hero who was useful to people but whose name wasn't recognised by people. In an SE community, "helpful" means accepted answer and "wasn't recognised by people" means didn't got upvotes.**